# Override Events in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-2.0, shadow, overriding

I would like to shadow/override an event in VB.NET.

I do it only because I have to implement in this object an interface, that contains the same event like the base object itself, and I need to keep this base event as is it without modification nor supplementary event additions.

How can I do it?

```
Public Shadows Event VisibleChanged As EventHandler Implements IVisibleChanged
```

So, I would like to implement a interface that contains VisibleChanged event, but to keep functional the myBase VisibleChanged event too.

```
  Public Shadows Event VisibleChanged As EventHandler Implements IVisibleChanged
    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
      AddHandler MyBase.VisibleChanged, value
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
      RemoveHandler MyBase.VisibleChanged, value
    End RemoveHandler
  End Event
```

something like this, but it seems Visual Studio does not recognize such a syntax...

I mean, in C# I realize it like this:

```
public new event EventHandler VisibleChanged
{
    add { base.VisibleChanged += value; }
    remove { base.VisibleChanged -= value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
  Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.'
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.'
    Dim b As New MyButton
    Me.Controls.Add(b)
    b.Name = "customButton"
    b.Location = New Point(10, 10)
    b.Text = "Hit me!"
    AddHandler CType(b, IMyInterface).Click, AddressOf MyButton1_Click
  End Sub

  Private Sub MyButton1_Click( _ 
      ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Debug.Print("{0} clicked!; ", CType(sender, Control).Name)
  End Sub
End Class

' ------- interface'
Public Interface IMyInterface
  Event Click As EventHandler
End Interface

' ------- class'
Public Class MyButton
  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Button
  Implements IMyInterface
  ' ============ HERE IS THE SOLUTION'
  Private Event Click1 As EventHandler Implements IMyInterface.Click

  Private Sub ResendClick( _ 
      ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
    RaiseEvent Click1(sender, e)
  End Sub
  ' END HERE IS THE SOLUTION ============ '
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Public Shadows Event VisibleChanged As EventHandler Implements IVisibleChanged
    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
      AddHandler MyBase.VisibleChanged, value
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
      RemoveHandler MyBase.VisibleChanged, value
    End RemoveHandler
  End Event
```

something like this, but it seems Visual Studio does not recognize such a syntax...

I mean, in C# I realize it like this:

```
public new event EventHandler VisibleChanged
{
    add { base.Click += value; }
    remove { base.Click -= value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When implementing an interface in VB.NET, you don't need to name the implementation the same name as the interface.

Example interface:

```
Public Interface IFoo
    Event Bar As EventHandler
End Interface
```

Example implementation:

```
Public Class FooImplementation
    Implements IFoo

    ' This is the built-in Bar event, specific to this class.
    Public Event Bar As EventHandler

    ' This is the implemented IFoo.Bar event.
    Public Event IFooBar As EventHandler Implements IFoo.Bar

End Class
```

When somebody is attached to you as an IFoo, they will get your IFooBar event:

```
Dim instance As IFoo = New FooImplementation()
AddHandler instance.Bar, AddressOf IFooBarHandler
```

When they're attached to you as FooImplementation, they'll get the Bar event and they will also be able to attach to IFooBar:

```
Dim instance As New FooImplementation()
AddHandler instance.Bar, AddressOf BarHandler
AddHandler instance.IFooBar, AddressOf IFooBarHandler
```

Comment: I reformulated(edited) my question thread. Hope this will bring some clarity in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Can you override the handler in a derived class?

```
Public Class OverriddenClass
Inherits OriginalClass
Protected Overrides Function ProcessVisibleChanged(ByRef msg as Message, value as ...) As Boolean
  value = value + 1
  ProcessVisibleChanged = MyBase.ProcessVisibleChanged(msg, value)
  ' or use OnVisibleChanged to avoid the base handler
End Function
end class
```

Comment: I use override **only** because the implementation of the interface requires that. I don't change *at all* the event behavior.